# Change localName of an individual using Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, apache-jena

I need to change the name of an individual. I have found that using the `getLocalName` you manage to print the name, but is it possible to change the name of an existing individual and propagate it over the whole graph?

I have thought on using `sameAs`, but although it is similar, it is not the same as I don't one the original name to be kept.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a change, the app needs to remove all the old statements and add all new statements. There isn't a way to change-in-place a single node in the graph.

There is a helper function for this `ResourceUtils.renameResource`.

`getLocal` is a function on the URI of an RDF Term - the resources don't store the namespace/localname, just the URI.

If you are doing this on a large database, it may be better to dump the database to N-Triples, run a text changing script, and reload the database.

Comment: I was just waiting the two days to post my answer which btw it was similar to yours ;) What I did was dumping the entities to NTriples and then by using regex I replaced all the IRIs at once. Thanks.